# clearTimout reference before initialization

Tags: asynchronous, scope, settimeout, svelte, cleartimeout

I need to clear this timeout before running the next. But how do i do that with the scope issue?

```js
function splashHandler() {
  clearTimeout(splashTimeout); // <--can't call before initialization...

  showSplash = true;

  let splashTimeout: NodeJS.Timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    showSplash = false;
  }, 2000);
}
```

UPDATED - used answer from below

```
//create a timeout variable...has to define it?
    let splashTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('set');
    }, 2000);

    //Clear and set the timeout...
    const splashTimeoutHandler = () => {
        showSplash = true;
        if (splashTimeout) {
            clearTimeout(splashTimeout);
            splashTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
                showSplash = false;
            }, 2000);
        }
    };
```

Comment: where is `splashTimeout` defined? Later. So bring it on top of the block scope. Or out of your function overall as scoped to your module.

Comment: The type is wrong, by the way, `setTimeout` in the browser returns a number. You can get the wrong type resolved if Node types are installed; can be avoided by using `window.setTimeout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the timeout in the module scope:

```js
let splashTimeout;

function splashHandler() {
  clearTimeout(splashTimeout);

  showSplash = true;

  splashTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    showSplash = false;
  }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: not sure why but the only difference in mine was I had to set  splashTimeout to something initially or didn't work. But this is the right answer. I updated above

Comment: @lache glad you made it work, and thanks for sharing your findings